# C# - Cannot connect my Socket Server

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, unity-game-engine, arduino

Good afternoon dear community,

I am currently working on a Arduino + Unity project where I am supposed to build an Arduino control through Unity. For that, I have set my Arduino and connected to wifi.

I built a Socket Server with C#. The problem is that: I am able to connect to this Socket Server through a Node.js Socket Client, however to check if my Arduino setup is broken, I have built a Node.js Socket Server and was able to connect my Node.js Socket server succesfully through Arduino. (The only reason I am using Node.js here is that because I am more fluent on that platform so I am able to check what is wrong, so final project does not have any Node.js.) So;

Node.js Client -> Unity C# Server (Works)

Arduino Client -> Node.js Server (Works) (Below is Arduino output)

```
AT+CIPSTART=3,"TCP","192.168.1.67",1234
OK
Linked
```

Arduino Client -> Unity C# Server (Does not work) (Below is Arduino output)

```
AT+CIPSTART=3,"TCP","192.168.1.67",1234
ERROR
Unlink
```

Below I am putting my all C#, Node.js and Arduino codes. I don`t think that there is an Arduino hardware issue here, but don·t understand why I cannot connect my 
Unity Socket Server.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using UnityEngine;

public class SocketScript : MonoBehaviour {
    Thread tcpListenerThread;

    void Start()
    {
        tcpListenerThread = new Thread(() => ListenForMessages(1234));
        tcpListenerThread.Start();
    }

    public void ListenForMessages(int port)
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {

            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.67");
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            server.Start();

            Byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            String data = null;

            while(true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Waiting for connection.");
                using (TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    Debug.Log("Connected!");
                    data = null;
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int i;

                    // As long as there is something in the stream:
                    while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Debug.Log(String.Format("Received: {0}", data));

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Debug.Log(String.Format("Sent: {0}", data));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(String.Format("SocketException: {0}", e));
        } finally
        {
            server.Stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Node.js Client:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '192.168.1.67';
var PORT = 1234;

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('Client connected to: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client 
    client.write('Hello World!');

});

client.on('data', function(data) {    
    console.log('Client received: ' + data);
     if (data.toString().endsWith('exit')) {
       client.destroy();
    }
});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Client closed');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Node.js Server:

```
var net = require('net');


// Configuration parameters
var HOST = '192.168.1.67';
var PORT = 1234;

// Create Server instance 
var server = net.createServer(onClientConnected);

server.listen(PORT, HOST, function() {  
  console.log('server listening on %j', server.address());
});

function onClientConnected(sock) {  
  var remoteAddress = sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort;
  console.log('new client connected: %s', remoteAddress);

  sock.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('%s Says: %s', remoteAddress, data);
    sock.write(data);
    sock.write(' exit');
  });

  sock.on('close',  function () {
    console.log('connection from %s closed', remoteAddress);
  });

  sock.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Connection %s error: %s', remoteAddress, err.message);
  });
};
```